# Gear VR + Trinus VR using a cable

Tags: samsung-gear-vr

I want to use Trinus VR with the cable using Gear VR. I could disable booting the Oculus app with Package Disabler Pro, but I'm not sure if I could pair PC and phone with cable since it's through Gear VR.

Does anyone know if it works?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because Gear VR isn't just the lens system, it also has better sensors.

Answer (score 0):

My friend has a Gear VR headset and I have wanted to do this for a while. I eventually just made it myself with Google Cardboard.

[Dan Hulme has a good point](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144004/gear-vr-trinus-vr-using-a-cable#comment185832_144004). The Gear VR does incorporate multiple other sensors the communicate with the phone. *However*, the phones compatible immediately with Gear VR all have a gyroscope in them so you don't really need the extra sensors.

You should be able to use the Trinus VR app but with only the built-in gyro, it might drift or lag a tad bit.

Answer (score -1):

Try [VRidge by Riftcat](https://riftcat.com/vridge). It will use your phone sensors data.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion, but their website says they don't support Gear VR (yet), only Cardboard. They're hoping to add Gear VR support but can't promise anything.

Comment: 2021 update: looks like it supports Gear VR (and other VR headsets) now.